# Refund stripe payment

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment

I am using the stripe connect feature. The payment feature is working fine but when I run stripe.refunds.create() method to refund the payment, though it returns successful status but the stripe dashboard does not update.

**Request:**

```js
const intent = await stripe.refunds.create({
  payment_intent: booking.paymentIntent,
  reason: 'requested_by_customer',
});
```

**Response:**

```js
{
  id: 're_*********************',
  object: 'refund',
  amount: 20000,
  balance_transaction: 'txn_*********************',
  charge: 'ch_*********************',
  created: 1670775881,
  currency: 'usd',
  metadata: {},
  payment_intent: 'pi_*********************',
  reason: 'requested_by_customer',
  receipt_number: null,
  source_transfer_reversal: null,
  status: 'succeeded',
  transfer_reversal: null
}
```

**Dashboard:**
[image]

I am new to stripe. If I am doing anything wrong please help me to find it or give me any article or doc. The stripe doc seems huge and confusing to me.

Comment: FYi Stripe has a discord channel for developer help.  I would try that, as I have gotten great support from that. https://dev.to/stripe/introducing-the-stripedev-discord-community-server-5g3l

Comment: Have you tested it in Stripe's very handy "Development Mode"?

Comment: I am using test mode.

Comment: It's best to reach out to Stripe Support and provide the concrete Id (either PaymentIntent Id or Refund Id) so they can look into detail for you.